# Как лучше написать таблицу в базе данных?

Tags: mysql

Я пишу crm. Создаю таблицу в базе данных "сделки". Будет постоянно увеличиваться или уменьшаться количество видов доп услуг. Мне новую колонку постоянно создавать под каждый доп? Из там до 20 штук может быть! Аналогично на складе подразделения может увеличиваться или уменьшаться количество инвентаря.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `salesdep_1.1_lid` (
  `id` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_client` int(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, -- клиент
  `id_responsible` int(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, -- ответственный
  `adress` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, -- адрес сделки
  `lid_datetime` datetime COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, -- дата и время сделки
  `cost` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, -- стоимость
  `type_clean` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, -- тип уборки
  `area_clean` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, -- площадь уборки
 (тут планировал добавить поля допуслуг и потом в таблице указывать наличие/отсутствие) 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: Из вашего вопроса непонятно как соотносятся "Сделки" и "Доп услуги". Накидайте хотя бы предполагаемую схему данных, а мы покритикуем

Comment: `id_client` int(50)  -- клиент
  `id_responsible` int(50) , -- ответственный
  `adress` varchar(100) , -- адрес сделки
  `lid_datetime` datetime  -- дата и время сделки
  `cost` varchar(100) , -- стоимость
  `type_clean` varchar(100)  -- тип уборки
  `первая допуслуга` varchar(100) 
  `ещё одна допуслуга` varchar(100)

Comment: То есть, в сделке у меня данные о предоставленных услугах, кем и кому выполнена и итоговая стоимость. Беда в том, что вот я выбрал тип убокри (клининговая компания), а допов в сделке может быть несколько (за список у меня соответственно отдельная таблица отвечает).

Comment: Отредактируйте свой вопрос и добавьте информацию туда. В комментариях без форматирования совершенно ничего не воспринимается

Comment: Сейчас подумал, что может отдельную таблицу создать, где будут данные типа: Id сделки / допуслуга / количество. То есть каждая услуга = строка.

Comment: Думаете в правильном направлении